# How do I count the number of changes in a given month in a SQL lookup table?

Tags: sql, database, report

I have a table in my SQL DB containing about 200 customers and their attributes (phone number, address, demographic, etc).

I need to find a way to count the **number of changes to existing records per month**. I could look at the "Date Modified" column to know when it was LAST updated and count how many records were changed in a given month, but if a customer updates their info once in January (making the count for January to increment by 1), then again in March (making the count for March to increment by 1), the count of changes in January will drop by 1.

My end goal is to generate a Power BI report that shows the total number of changes made each month in the last 12 months.

Should I have a separate table that acts like an audit trail to count all these changes? Or is there another best practice?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to create an audit trail by creating a trigger on the table for anytime an update is made it inserts the data into the audit trail table with a CreateDate column which is defaulted to sysdatetime(). Once that is completed then you can accurately report on it, plus you will have a running history of any change that was ever made if that is important.

Comment: I will explore this, thank you. I am able to visualize this concept. To set this up, should I use the PK of the main lookup table (aka my customer table) as the FK of the audit trail table?

Comment: @Nixu I would, as this will help maintain the relationship between both tables.